# Accessing angular directive (element)'s text inside the template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I am following [this EggHead.io tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A6wq16Ow5Ec) on custom components, and I came across this problem. When declaring a directive such as:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('myDir', function(){
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            controller: "myController",
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.foo = element.text();
            },
            templateUrl: "myDirTemplate.html"
        }
    });
```

and the Template being:

```
<div>The value is: {{foo}}</div>
```

and the directive being used such as follows:

```
<html>
...
<myDir>Bar</myDir> 
...
</html>
```

*element* in the *link function* refers to the

```
<div>The value is: {{foo}}</div>
```

in the template. If I don't specify the *templateUrl*, then *element* refers to the

```
<myDir>Bar</myDir>
```

in the main view, which is what I want. I was hoping the directive would take the "Bar" text and insert it into the {{foo}}, giving the final result of:

```
<div>The value is: Bar</div>
```

But I don't know how to get around angular selecting the template's element every single time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to use [ngTransclude](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngTransclude):

```js
app.directive('myDir', function(){
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: "myDirTemplate.html",
    replace: true
  }
});
```

and then your external template becomes something similar to:

```
<div>The value is: <span ng-transclude></span></div>
```

View the code working here: http://plnkr.co/edit/EuT5UlgyxgM8d54pTpOr?p=preview