# Access template right after it is inserted in Angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How do you access the template in the link function?

The following simple code shows my problem.

```
.directive('mydirective', function(){

   return {
      link: function() {
          console.log(document.getElementById('mytemplate')); //Here it is null
      },

      template: '<div id="mytemplate"></div>' 
   }
})
```

**UPDATE**

I just realized that using `find` method on the "element" argument of the link function works.

```
link: function(scope, ele) {
   ele.find('#myTemplate'); //This works!
}
```

Is it because the template is not yet added to the document  - but in some JQLite execution context?

Comment: maybe this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115238/accessing-angular-directive-elements-text-inside-the-template?rq=1

Comment: By the way, why would you want to access your template inside the link function?

Comment: Sorry, that question is about transcluding. I need to run some JS against my template after it is inserted.

Comment: The way of thinking in angularJS should be different than in vanilla JS. In AngularJS, the dom is responsible for running required pieces of code.  In your case, you should create a new directive that will be inserted inside your template.

Comment: e.g.: have a look at this directive for adding a datepicker to an input: https://github.com/luisfarzati/ng-bs-daterangepicker/blob/master/src/ng-bs-daterangepicker.js

Comment: But we can uses the "elem" argument of the link function to access the template without a brand new directive for this.

Comment: Let me rephrase what I wanted to say.  Inside the link function, you won't be able to run some code in a Jquery way. You can manipulate your template, but doing something like ``ele.find('#myTemplate').someJqueryThing();`` won't work.

Comment: "Is it because the template is not yet added to the document - but in some JQLite execution context?" - Yes

Comment: `ele.find('#myTemplate').someJqueryThing();` if this `someJqueryThing` is permitted in JQlite, that still is very Angular.